# When I add Sort() in elasticsearch (NEST) I don't get any hits

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When I sort like this:

```
.Sort(sortDescriptor => sortDescriptor.Descending(product => product.TopProduct))
```

I have no hits. Any idea why? Is the syntax wrong or what? I got this from the official NEST/elasticsearch docs site.

**SOLUTION**

I had to add `.Suffix("keyword")` like this:

```
.Sort(sortDescriptor => sortDescriptor.Descending(product => product.TopProduct.Suffix("keyword")))
```

And it worked. I had to use the "keyword" subfield on "TopProduct".

> **Default mapping for String propertiesedit:** 
>   When using Auto Mapping, the inferred mapping for a string POCO type is a text datatype with
>   multi fields including a keyword sub field

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html#_default_mapping_for_string_properties

> If you index a string with no mapping, ES in 5.0+ now automatically
>   creates a text version and a keyword version (under .keyword) of the
>   field. - dakroneLee HinmanElastic Team Member

Source: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-sorting-on-text-string-field-no-longer-available-in-5-x/68586/4

This worked but could someone explain to me how the text and keyword datatypes work?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `text` and `keyword` as I think they explain the difference well: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html

Comment: @RussCam I was searching for those on the same website but couldn't figure out how to get to them. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)